# How to keep graph objects for further use outside the completion handler block in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks

I use the following code to send a request to the graph api and display it in a label

```
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"40123148903?fields=picture" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphObject> result, NSError *error)
     {
         if(!error)
         {
              self.tryLabal.text = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"url"];

         }
     }
     ];
```

The problem is it only lets me use the graph object inside the block. I want to keep the returned result.

I tried declaring a id property and assigning it the result id

```
self.tryGraphObject = result;
```

I have some more information thanks to a member here:
in ios facebook sdk 3.0 we handled the results from an graph api call with a facebook delegate that was called when a reply came back. now in 3.1 they changed the logic so that each request comes with a block called "completion hander" that lets you handle the results. problem is i can't save the results for further use because for some reason it doesn't let me

**edit:** turns out I was wrong, the problem is different. I broke the code down and it turns out I thought it wasn't setting the property, but it was. just after the view loaded. basically it kept running the code while its waiting for the reply from Facebook which means the view loaded before the values returned so it displays a view based on empty properties. what can I do?

Comment: so what is wrong with `self.tryGraphObject = result;`?

Answer (score -2):

Above your block you can declare a graph class you made like this

```
__block FBGraphObject *graphObject = self.tryGraphObject;
```

Then in the block, set it to the graphObject, it should be pointed to your self.tryGraphObject and when you set it in the block, it should set it hopefully. I've not fully tested this yet.

Another possibility is to do

```
self.trypGraphObject = [result copy];
```

And the only other thing I can think of is that the result object is an id, so try typecasting it before setting

```
self.tryGraphObject = (FBGraphObject *)[result copy];
```

or

```
FBGraphObject *graph = (FBGraphObject *)result;
self.tryGraphObject = graph;
```

That is all I can think of right now. I hope this points you to the right direction.